# breaks and values not matching up in plot when using scale_color_manual in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I am trying to graph multiple graphs using the same colors (values) for each group I am plotting using scale_color_manual. It seems to work well for many of the graphs, but not all and I cannot seem to figure out why.

I have set breaks to the exact names they are within my .csv (data frame) and made a vector for my color values to correspond as well as labels.
x and y are similar to data I'm trying to graph. 
I would like both of these to have the same colors for each genus when graphed.

````
x <- data.frame ("Genus" =c("unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum" ,"Planktothrix " ,"Other", "Microcystis "
,"unknown Synechococcaceae  " ,"unknown Chroococcales ","unknown Oscillatoriophycideae","Pseudanabaena ","Synechococcus, ", "unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum" ,"Planktothrix " ,"Other", "Microcystis "
,"unknown Synechococcaceae  "), "RelativeAB"= c( 22, 35, 46, 71, 44, 27, 17, 87, 67, 44, 17, 88, 15, 77, 99, 20), factor= c( "control", "control", "control", "control", "pulex", "pulex", "pulex", "pulex" ,"magna", "magna", "magna", "magna", "dilution", "dilution", "dilution", "dilution")

y <- data.frame ("Genus" =c("unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum" ,"Planktothrix " ,"Other", "Microcystis "
,"unknown Synechococcaceae  " ,"unknown Oscillatoriophycideae","Pseudanabaena ","Synechococcus, ", "unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum" ,"Planktothrix " ,"Other", "Microcystis "
,"unknown Synechococcaceae  "), "RelativeAB"= c( 22, 35, 46, 71, 44, 27, 17, 87, 67, 44, 17, 15, 77, 99, 20), factor= c( "control", "control", "control", "pulex", "pulex", "pulex", "pulex" ,"magna", "magna", "magna", "magna", "dilution", "dilution", "dilution", "dilution")

colorscyano <-c("#CC0000", "#FF6000", "#CC9900", "#336600", "#3333FF", "#9933CC", "#FF66CC", "#66FFFF", "#99FF33", "#FFFF00")
breakscyano <- c("unknown Cyanobacteria"
                 ,"Dolichospermum"
                 ,"Planktothrix "
                 ,"Pseudanabaena "
                 ,"Synechococcus "
                 ,"Other"
                 ,"Microcystis "
                 ,"unknown Synechococcaceae  "
                 ,"unknown Chroococcales "
                 ,"unknown Oscillatoriophycideae")

labscyano <-c(expression("Unknown" ~"cyanobacteria")
              ,expression(paste(italic("Dolichospermum")))
              ,expression(paste(italic("Planktothrix")))
              ,expression(paste(italic("Pseudanabaena")))
              ,expression(paste(italic("Synechococcus")))
              ,"Other"
              , expression(paste(italic("Microcystis")))
              , expression (paste("unknown", ~italic("Synechococcaceae")))
              , expression (paste("unknown",~italic("Chroococcales")))
              , expression (paste("unknown",~italic("Oscillatoriophycideae"))))

ggplot(x, aes(x=factor, y=RelativeAB, fill=Genus)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=0.5, color="black")+
scale_fill_manual(values = colorscyano, breaks= breakscyano, labels=labscyano)+
  theme_classic()```
````

Not all of the graphs have all groups listed, but since they are matched to the breaks, I think the colors should match between graphs?
However when I plot the graph it does not match up correctly.

The only difference between the data is that this one has one less point within one of the factors, but I feel that should not matter since the breaks (names in .csv) are the same and should still match with the values...

Comment: It's possible you need `limits`, not `breaks` (since I often make that mistake with discrete data :) ). You may also need to pass a named vector for the colors.  Like `names(colorscyano) = breakscyano` and then pass that to `values`.

Comment: YES! limits worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Follow-up question...
How would I remove the un-used limits from the legend, why is this not a default (I tried drop=TRUE with no success)?

Comment: @MeganLadds Please pose that as a new question. The chance of a follow up question getting sufficient attention in comments is rather low. Please also take note of the advice posted by MrFlick, & provide a reproducible example this time.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with erroneous extra white spaces that you have in the data fields. If they are removed your plots seem to like like expected:

```r
library(ggplot2)

x <- data.frame(
  Genus = c("unknown Cyanobacteria", "Dolichospermum", "Planktothrix ", "Other", "Microcystis", "unknown Synechococcaceae", "unknown Chroococcales", "unknown Oscillatoriophycideae", "Pseudanabaena","Synechococcus", "unknown Cyanobacteria", "Dolichospermum", "Planktothrix ", "Other", "Microcystis", "unknown Synechococcaceae"),
  RelativeAB = c(22, 35, 46, 71, 44, 27, 17, 87, 67, 44, 17, 88, 15, 77, 99, 20),
  factor = c("control","control","control","control","pulex","pulex","pulex","pulex","magna","magna","magna","magna","dilution","dilution","dilution","dilution")
)

y <- data.frame (
  Genus = c("unknown Cyanobacteria", "Dolichospermum","Planktothrix","Other","Microcystis","unknown Synechococcaceae","unknown Oscillatoriophycideae","Pseudanabaena","Synechococcus","unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum","Planktothrix" ,"Other","Microcystis","unknown Synechococcaceae"),
  RelativeAB = c(22, 35, 46, 71, 44, 27, 17, 87, 67, 44, 17, 15, 77, 99, 20),
  factor = c("control","control","control","pulex","pulex","pulex","pulex","magna","magna","magna","magna","dilution","dilution","dilution","dilution")
)

colorscyano <- c("#CC0000","#FF6000","#CC9900","#336600","#3333FF","#9933CC","#FF66CC","#66FFFF","#99FF33","#FFFF00")
breakscyano <- c("unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum","Planktothrix","Pseudanabaena","Synechococcus","Other","Microcystis","unknown Synechococcaceae","unknown Chroococcales","unknown Oscillatoriophycideae")

labscyano <- c(
  expression("Unknown" ~ "cyanobacteria"),
  expression(paste(italic("Dolichospermum"))),
  expression(paste(italic("Planktothrix"))),
  expression(paste(italic("Pseudanabaena"))),
  expression(paste(italic("Synechococcus"))),
  "Other",
  expression(paste(italic("Microcystis"))),
  expression (paste("unknown", ~ italic("Synechococcaceae"))),
  expression (paste("unknown",  ~ italic("Chroococcales"))),
  expression (paste("unknown",  ~ italic("Oscillatoriophycideae")
  ))
)

ggplot(x, aes(x=factor, y=RelativeAB, fill=Genus)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=0.5, color="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorscyano, breaks= breakscyano, labels=labscyano)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(y, aes(x=factor, y=RelativeAB, fill=Genus)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=0.5, color="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorscyano, breaks= breakscyano, labels=labscyano)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>